# Categorise a Column Of Text Strings Using a List in Another Column - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with text strings in and I would like to categorise them according to a keyword in that string.

For example, in column A:

- i use php
- i use java
- i uses angular
- i used javascript

And in column B:

- Platform
- Platform
- Platform
- Platform

The category for all of these would be "Platform" and the keywords used to categorise would be:
Column C:

- php
- java
- angular
- javascript

But I want to have a column with the keywords to trigger the categorisation so I just add or take away the triggering keywords.

I am using:

=IFNA(IFS
(
REGEXMATCH(A2, "php|java|javascript|angular"),"Platform"
),"Generic")

I want to use something like this:
=IFNA(IFS
(
REGEXMATCH(A2, C:C),"Platform"
),"Generic")

Where C:C contains the list of keywords

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IIt6IrXmTrl9mQFAGx1CWozD9J2gaE8_uRy_aLSKosU/edit?usp=sharing

I hope you can help.

Comment: objective is unclear. pls provide more details

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)), {C:C, B:B}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I would like it if I could specify the category in the formula like this: =INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)), "Platform", 2, 0)))  But I know this does not work :)

Comment: =IFNA(IFS
(
REGEXMATCH(A2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)),"Platform"))